# Is there something like Grunt (config) templates for Gulp.js?

Tags: gruntjs, gulp

Is there any plugin that adds a template-like functionality in Gulp.js?

I.e. how to get the output filename of the following task, without defining `stylesOutputFilename` variable?

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return merge(
            // stream 1
            gulp.src([
                paths.vendor + '/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less',
                paths.vendor + '/font-awesome/less/font-awesome.less'
            ])
            .pipe(less({
                modifyVars: {
                    '@icon-font-path': '"'+paths.web+'/"',
                    '@fa-font-path':   '"'+paths.web+'"',
                }
            }))
            ,
            // stream 2
            gulp.src([
                paths.vendor + '/OwlCarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css',
                paths.vendor + '/OwlCarousel/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css',
            ])
        )
        .pipe(concat(pkg.name))
        .pipe(minifyCss({}))
        .pipe(rename({extname: '.css', suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.css.dest));
});
```